# explain this regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am new to regular expression,
can anyone help me out what this lines says:

```
$body = preg_replace('/\s{6,}/ms','',$body);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\s{6,}` means six of more whitespace characters...

Answer (score 2):

```
$body = preg_replace('/\s{6,}/ms','',$body);
```

Replace space (`\s`), which occurs 6 to undefined times (`{6,}`) with nothing. Do this multiline. (`/m`). The `s` could be removed, it adds no value when you don't use the "all characters" character (`.`).

Comment: \s are not just spaces; the multiline modifier is useless too btw

Comment: Can you explain why the multiline modifier is useless? `$body` cannot contain a multine string?

Comment: @m0skit0 Well, it could be multiline, but it'll still only replace 6 or more whitespaces in a row.

Comment: @m0skit0 How is _regex_ modifier related to whether $body contains line terminators or not?

Comment: Multiline mode merely changes the meaning of the start and end anchors (`^` and `$`), making them *start-of-line* and *end-of-line* anchors.  There are no anchors in the regex, so the `m` modifier is useless.

Answer (score 1):

It removes occurrences of at least 6 consecutive white space characters.

> **\s - white space**
>
> Defined as (horizontal) tab, space, line feed, carriage return or form feed.

The pattern modifiers are useless btw:

- `m` changes the behavior of `^` and `$`
- `s` makes `.` match newline characters as well; otherwise it would stop at the end of a line.

Comment: it means if there are more than 6 consecutive white space then it will work, and if less than 6, it will not work. right?

Comment: It always works. If there are 6+ spaces, it will erase them. If not, it will do nothing.

Comment: @m0skit0 not just spaces, also horizontal tabs, line feeds, carriage returns and form feeds

Answer (score 0):

Basically its saying replace anything with six spaces in a row.

```
\s  = space
{6,} = between 6 and (since the second number after the comman is blank) 6
\ms = Used together, as /ms, they let the "." match any character whatsoever, while still allowing "^" and "$" to match, respectively, just after and just before newlines within the string.
```

Also have a peek at the [perldoc for perl regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) may be helpful in the future.

Comment: You shouldn't link to Perl's regex documentation since this is PHP. Also you didn't specify with what the 6+ spaces are replaced :)

Comment: @m0skit0 I know this is php but it uses preg uses the PCRE pattern matching system (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)

Comment: I know too, but PCRE, despite the name, [are not Perl's regexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcre).

Comment: Well, then as I said, that link is not correct for PCRE's (it's correct for Perl though) ;)

Comment: It details regular expressions pretty well though, so your saying we should never link to articles which are from different languages just because they don't aren't specifically the same language despite having educational benefit?

Comment: Right, but if you link to an article for that language, it's even better :)